# MyBase initialize() in Membership Provider

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-membership

In my code I use this line to Initialize my Base:

```
MyBase.Initialize(name, config)
```

Everything goes fine in the first time pass... but when it passes second time then throws me an error `The Base Is already Initialized` and that is something I don't want to happen.
Is there any way to catch this event?

Comment: Why are you running that more than once?

Comment: Because happen many times to pass from the same page twice. or from the same button twice

Comment: Even if I put it in the `Default.aspx` Page

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you should never initialize the provider more than once.

Comment: I use an `If ... Then` to catch the issue of this initialize Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that at all.  If you code ends up trying to initialize more than once, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45743/discussion-between-lefteris-gkinis-and-slaks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the Base initialized only in the `Default.aspx` page, putting these lines in the Page_Load:

```
Dim myNewAsp As New AspNetSqlProvider
        If MyAspNetSqlMembershipProvider.SQLconnectionString = Nothing Then
            myNewAsp.InitializeSite(sender, e)
            Return
        End If
```

Doing this the system always knows when if the Base is initialized or not.